# Show/Hide divs with checkboxes using if/else

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, checkbox, show-hide

Totally new to any type of coding past HTML/CSS.  I tried looking around but I wasn't sure how to apply solutions to my specific problem.  I have a list of checkboxes as such:

`<input type="checkbox" value="de-borders" /> Choose my border`

When you hit the submit button (there's 5 checkboxes), it's supposed to show the divs of the ones checked.  So I have a function linked to the a href of the submit.  Problem I'm having is if the user UNCHECKS a box, and hits submit again, I need those boxes to disappear.

This is what I have (I had help so I don't get it entirely):

```
  var show_panels =(function(){
    $("#de-options input").each(function(index, element) {
        var val = $(element).attr('value');
        if ($("#de-options input").is(":checked"))
        {
            $('#' + val).show();
        }
        else
        {
             $('#' + val).hide();
        }
      });
  });
```

Where I have the 'if' is the problem.  Because of the .each I don't know how to specify 'look at these checkboxes and if they're checked ...' because the '$de-options' that I have there now just shows all of them regardless of what I have checked.

So really I just need to know what to put for 'if.'

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("#de-options input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#' + val).show();
        } else {
            $('#' + val).hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: not right. `:` indicates meta selector, your first one should be `[type=checkbox]`, second one is correct

Answer (score 0):

You're building a variable called "val" that is set to "$(element).attr('value');". In your example, the value of the checkbox is "de-borders" so in this case, val="de-borders"... fine so far. However, once in your if statement, it's trying to hide $('#' + val), or $('#de-borders'). This is saying to hide the element on the page with the ID of de-borders, which doesn't exist.

Instead, replace the contents of the if/else with:
$(element).show(); and $(element).hide();

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  Thank you!  And thank you everyone else for your responses. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your HTML looks like this. Assuming it is like this and this should work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="de-options">
  <input type="checkbox" value="de-borders" /> Choose First
  <input type="checkbox" value="de-borders2" /> Choose Srcond
  <input type="checkbox" value="de-borders3" /> Choose Third
</div>

<div id="de-borders"> Div One</div>
<div id="de-borders2">Div Two</div>
<div id="de-borders3">Div Three</div>

<input type="submit" value="save" />
```

**Script**

$(function(){

```
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

     $("#de-options input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
       var item= $(this);
       var val = item.attr('value');
       if (item.is(":checked"))
       {
         $('#' + val).show();
       }
       else
       {
          $('#' + val).hide();
       }
    });
  });

});
```

Here is the working sample http://jsfiddle.net/hzpVy/15/